# Steampunk tabletop RPG set in a Victorian society on fragments of planets

Tags: story-identification, rpg

I'm trying to find a tabletop RPG system probably from the late 2000s. I have seen people running around with "game tester" t-shirts in 2014+ in Germany, during my studies in Nuremberg, so the date must be close to that.

The game was published either in German or English, I tend to confuse the two.

I mostly remember the manual that I had downloaded back then, 300+ pages PDF with heavy use of black and white formatting.

The setting was steampunk centric, with small robots and a Victorian society, but also non-human characters (spider-humans of sorts?). The world was established on fragments of planets, with gravity erratic towards the edges of the shards. I believe you could travel between different planetary fragments with ships.

There were some sort of soul-eating mechanism, the game revolved around gathering your soul shards and rebuilding your soul.

In terms of game mechanics, I believe it was based on 2d calculations, where you would have a number of 50% changes on each roll and the sum of positive rolls determined the outcome. (something akin to: roll 6d6, all even numbers count towards the outcome? I'm hazy.)

In my mind the game's name contained some variation of "opus" or "opera", but a search on [Wikipedia's list of tabletop games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tabletop_role-playing_games) does not return anything.

Comment: Sadly I have no idea, steampunk isn't my cup of tea. But if anything else fails, you could take a look here: https://rpggeek.com/rpggenre/166/steampunk. To limit the number of items returned, select "Core Rules (min needed to play)" under "Category", so it's only 170 games to check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Zab Zonk's comment and list of RPGs, I found it. It is Opus Anima, published in 2008 and little activity afterwards. A shame, given the effort put into the book and graphics. (Download version [here](http://www.opusanima.de/Herunterladen/OA_GRW_webversion.pdf))

Thanks for the list!

Comment: I read a post somewhere...1 to 3 years ago, that the publisher wants to give Opus Anima a new shot as a setting for FATE. Sadly, I never heard something about it, again.
There was a single follow up book, called 'Opus Anima Investigations', centered on non-supernatural investigators.